# onload event that fires when all assets are loaded, including those with async=true

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

What is a dom event like `window.onload` that fires when all assets are loaded including those with `async="true"` ?

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <script src="index.js" type="text/javascript" async="true"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      window.onload = function() {} // run when index.js loaded ???
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: In my tests, onload runs before async scripts are loaded.

Comment: In browsers that support _async_, they tend to also support _load_ events for those _Elements_, http://pieisgood.org/test/script-link-events/

Comment: This is when you start needing a script loader like requirejs

Comment: Does this help? http://javascript.info/tutorial/onload-ondomcontentloaded

Comment: There's no magic bullet for this, you'll have to roll your own or use a loader as suggested above.

Comment: Quick test - http://runnable.com/U43tTz7fsu8hJabW/ajax-for-jquery-and-dom

Comment: relevant http://www.phpied.com/non-onload-blocking-async-js/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't exists. When you define async=true you are saying to browser to not execute sequentially this script, so it will start executing just after be loaded. As you cannot add a callback to your script tag, maybe the best solution is to re-execute the window.onload listener at the end of your script.